# For Loop Stalls on Second Time in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make some code that should keep track of a win/loss ratio. I have a for loop that checks if a name is present in a separate variable, this works but when I try to do it again it stalls.

```
System.out.println("\nEnter Name 1");
scan.nextLine();
String name1 = scan.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    if (name1.equals(players[i].name)) {
        players[i].win++;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println("\nEnter Name 2");
scan.nextLine();
String name2 = scan.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    if (name2.equals(players[i].name)) {
        players[i].loss++;
        break;
    }
}
```

After the code it should go back to a while loop, but it just stalls instead. If I comment out the name 2 part, the code works, but I need both parts.

Edit 1:
Heres the whole code

```
public class Counter {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int intTemp;
        String stringTemp;

        int keepGoing = 1;
        int numPlayers = 0;
        Player[] players = new Player[999];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Melee Score Tracker");

        while (keepGoing == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nPrint Scores\t1\nNew Match\t2\nNew Player\t3\nExit\t\t4");
            intTemp = scan.nextInt();

            // Print Scores
            if (intTemp == 1) {

                intTemp = 0;
                System.out.print("\n");
                for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                    players[i].print();
                }

            }

            // New Match
            if (intTemp == 2) {

                intTemp = 0;
                System.out.println("\nEnter Name 1");
                scan.nextLine();
                String name1 = scan.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                    if (name1.equals(players[i].name)) {
                        players[i].win++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("\nEnter Name 2");
                scan.nextLine();
                String name2 = scan.nextLine();
                for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
                    if (name2.equals(players[i].name)) {
                        players[i].loss++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // New Player
            if (intTemp == 3) {

                intTemp = 0;
                System.out.println("\nWhat's the player's name?");
                scan.nextLine();
                stringTemp = scan.nextLine();
                players[numPlayers] = new Player();
                players[numPlayers].name = stringTemp;
                numPlayers++;
                System.out.println(numPlayers);

            }

            // Exit
            if (intTemp == 4) {

                System.exit(0);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I dont even see the while loop

Comment: Can you post your while loop, it may stall because it is running infinetely

Comment: Does it stall at `scan.nextLine();` (before the `String name2 = scan.nextLine();`)???

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure it enters in the for and doesn't get stalled while waiting for "next Line"?

Comment: I added the rest of the code to the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stalls because of this;

```
scan.nextLine();
scan.nextLine();
String name2 = scan.nextLine();
```

It is waiting for input 3 times. You only want input once so replace it with;

```
String name2 = scan.nextLine();
```

In the future things like this can easily be debugged by checking if the code actually enters the for loop by printing out a little message in the loop.

```
String name2 = scan.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
    System.out.println("We have entered the loop.");
    if (name2.equals(players[i].name)) {
        players[i].loss++;
        break;
    }
}
```

If you see output in the console then you know the problem is not with the loop itself, but is before it.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I did this because it was skipping to the next part of the code before when I didn't do this.